# How does the ECDSA work in signing and verifying signatures?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, blockchain, digital-signature, cryptocurrency

Can someone please tell me in simple terms how digital signatures are signed and verified with ECDSA? I'm trying to understand it and also making the algorithm, because I need it for my project. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about programming. Did you read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and [NIST 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) The algorithm is simple but the rest is not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.